# I want to stop a button from working after 10 commands have been done

Tags: jquery, button

Me and some friends have been doing a kind of a random generator for people who have a hard time deciding of where to eat or what to do as an example.
now you can add how many alternatives as you like, but after you have added 10 alternatives the alternatives goes down under the screen, what i want to do is to make it possible so that you can only add 10 alternatives.
sorry if the text was confusing.

HTML:

```
<div id="article">
    <div id="input">
    <form id="formen">
    Skriv in förslag:<input type="text" name="message" id="box" placeholder="Skriv förslag här!" required>

    <button id="val">Lägg till! </button><br>
    </form>
    <div id="messages"></div>
    <button id="kor">Välj!</button>
    </div>

    <div id="vinst">
     <h1>Och vinnaren blev:</h1>
    </div>
    </div>
```

button val is the button that adds the alternative being written into our textox "box".
this is our jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#val').click(function() {
    var toAdd = $("input[name=message]").val();
    if(toAdd == ""){
    }
    else{
    $('#messages').append("<p>"+toAdd+"</p>");
    $('#box').val(''); //remove text in textbox//
    e.preventDefault();
    }
});
$('#formen').on("keyup keypress", function(e) {
var code = e.keyCode || e.which; 
if (code  == 13) {               
e.preventDefault();
return false;
  }
 });

$('#kor').click(function() {
var random = Math.floor((Math.random()*$("#messages>p").length));

   $('#vinst').append("<p>"+($("#messages>p").eq(random).text())+"</p>");

});
});
```

since there were many brackets in the jQuery i hope that all of the brackets are visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a variables and make a loop after every comment +1 the variable that you set.

```
var countComments = 0;
while(//code){
    //code
    countComments += 1;
}
```

[Update]

```
if (countComments == 10) {
   //do nothing;
} else {
   //run comments.
}
```

Comment: i do not really get this thing to work, could you please help me on where to put theese things using the jquery code above? cause i do not really know where to put everything

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like this?

```
<button id="val" data-count="0">Lägg till! </button>
```

and change your javascript to

```
$('#val').click(function() {

var count = parseInt($(this).data("count"));

var toAdd = $("input[name=message]").val();

if(count<10)
{
    if(toAdd == ""){

    }
    else {
        $('#messages').append("<p>"+toAdd+"</p>");
        $('#box').val(''); //remove text in textbox//

        $(this).data("count",count+1));
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
});
```

I hope I understood what you wanted to do okay.
This way it makes sure that the count belongs to that button too, incase you wanted to expand later